# Storing User Input in An Arry and Printing it Back to the User in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to be able to ask the user to input 12 characters and integers and then print it back to the user. The characters are musical notes, and the integers are the length of each note in seconds.

Here is my code:

```
//Include Standard IO
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//----------
//----------Main Function----------
//----------


int main()
{

//Request Notes off of the user
printf(" Please enter a musical sequence of 15 notes in capitals: ");
printf("\n Please use the # character if needed");
printf("\n Please enter the time you want each note to last in seconds");


//Declare and initialize a table of notes as chars
int notelist[12];
int*ptr;
ptr = notelist;
//Creating the array for the single notes
char note[3];
//Creating a variable for the beginning of the note
int start;
//Declare and initialize a table of integers for the length of each note
int notelength[20];
//Creating a variable for the length of the note
int time;
//Creating a variable for the loop so that it runs 15 times
int loop;


    //Creating a loop that will run 15 times for the 15 note values
    for(loop=1; loop<4; loop++)

    {
        //Request a note off the user
        printf("\n\n Please enter a note in capitals: ");
        //Taking the input from the user
        scanf("%s", note);

        //Ask the user for the length he/she wants each note to be
        printf("\n Please enter the length you want each note to be in seconds: ");
        //Taking the input from the user
        scanf("%d", &time);
        notelength[time]=time+1;
    }

    //Print the input from the user back
    for(start=1; start<4; start++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &*ptr++);
    }

    for(start=1; start<4; start++)
    {
        printf("%d", *ptr++);
    }


//Return 0 to let the OS know the program finished successfully
return 0;
}
```

How can I store the 12 notes and lengths entered by the user and print it back to them when the loop is finished?

Comment: How can I store the 12 notes and lengths entered by the user and print it back to them when the loop is finished?

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamically allocated stack to store all notes which later you can print. Any data structure book or online tutorial will help.